# Strong Relationship Between Abstract and Geometric Dual of a Finite Graph

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs, cut-space

In what follows, a graph is always a finite multigraph with loops. A geometric dual of a graph is formed by embedding that graph in the plane (taking a set of points for the vertices and curves with non-intersecting interiors between them for the edges), assigning to each face (connected component of the complement of the embedding) a vertex as a point in the face, and connecting vertices with an edge passing through the edge connecting their faces (and intersecting nothing else in its interior), or adding self-loops in the case of an face that borders itself. An abstract dual of a graph $G$ is a graph $G^*$ with a bijection between the set of edges of $G$ and that of $G^*$ such that a set $E$ of edges of $G$ is a cycle if and only if its image is a cutset of $G^*$.

I know that a graph has an abstract dual if and only if it has a geometric dual, but I was wondering if the notions were more closely related. We have a relation $R$ on graphs, such that for graphs $G$ and $H$, $H\in R[G]$ if and only if $H$ is an abstract dual of $G$. I think I’ve shown to myself that $R^3=R$, where $R^3$ is referring to the composition of relations.

Now, take a graph $G$ and start with $S_0[G]=\{G\}$. Take all embeddings of $G$ into the plane, take all graphs corresponding geometric duals of these embeddings, and all graphs with embeddings of which the embedding of $G$ is the geometric dual. Thus, we obtain a new set $S_1[G]$. Apply the previous construction to every member of $S_1$ and take the union of sets obtained in this manner to form $S_2[G]$. Repeat to obtain $S_n[G]$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Take the union $S[G]$ of $S_n[G]$ for all odd $n$. Let us continue with this notation, and speak of the relation $S$ on finite graphs.

It is clear using $R^3=R$ that for all graphs $G$, $S[G]⊆R[G]$. However, I was wondering if $S[G]=R[G]$. In other, less precise, words, every abstract dual arises from geometric duals. Furthermore, is there some $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $S_n[G]=S[G]$, for all $G$? Can it be independent of $G$?

Comment: This would be a good question if you defined your terms. A google search can tell someone what an abstract dual or geometric dual could be (though even then, self-contained questions are better), but it can't tell anyone what they mean in your case. Do you allow multigraphs? Do you allow graphs that are not connected? Are you using the definition using spanning trees, or the definition using cuts and cycles?

Comment: The issue is resolved.